# Passport JWT - Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm having a problem where its always returning unauthorized for me. When i set the header Authorization to the token that received. It returns back with.

> Unauthorized

.

```
router.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {

    res.json('It worked: User ID is: ' + req.user._id);

});
```

.

```
var jwtOptions = {

    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
    secretOrKey: config.jwt.secretOrKey
    //issuer: config.jwt.issuer,
    //audience: config.jwt.audience,
};

passport.use(new JWTStrategy(jwtOptions, (jwt_payload, done) => {

    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, (err, user) => {

        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        return done(null, user);

    });

}));
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the same `SecretKey` both for signing the token and verifying the incoming token and also be sure that you keep the token expiration time long enough so that it doesn't expire soon before your testing.

Answer (score 14):

You have to change these things:

1) You have to change
   `jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),` to `jwtFromRequest :ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),`

2) Set the header:
    `Authorization:Bearer {token}`

3)  `jwt_payload._id` change to  `jwt_payload._doc._id`

Comment: This worked for me except the third step only needed to be what you signed the token with (in my case it was the username)

Comment: `Set the header: Authorization:Bearer {token}` worked for me.

Comment: The third point may change depending on versions of **passport** and **passport-jwt**. You should always check the content  with `console.log(jwt_payload)`. In some cases (passport 0.4.0 and passport-jwt 4.0.0) you should use  **jwt_payload.payload._id**.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same problem! The code below worked for me.

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findById(jwt_payload._id, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
};
```

The problem lies with `User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, ...`

Also while attaching the token to the header use the 'beforeSend' in the AJAX call in this format:

```
$.ajax({
        url:  url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: console.log("Error");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably must have made a mistake in the `request header`.
As per the [README](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt), it should be `'Authorization' = 'bearer token_received_on_login'`

Answer (score 0):

Just one change needed, use `jwt_payload._doc.id` instead of `jwt_payload.id`

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the header from `res.json({token: 'JWT ' + token})` to `res.json({token: 'Bearer ' + token})`
2. `jwt_payload.data._id` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

VS code server hangup this will happen because of some mistakes in your code.
its not specific to any common code change.
It can be any of the small code mistakes done by you.
In my case
i was using

```
app.use(express.json)
```

instead of

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was not using the same secret value to sign and extract the jwt. After setting the same secret value to both scenarios authentication worked like a charm.

when creating the jwt using jsonwebtoken npm package

```
const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: "1d" })
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Logged in successfully!",
            token: "Bearer " + token
        })
```

When extracting the jwt inside passport

```
const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET
};

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    console.log("jwt_payload", jwt_payload)
    UserModel.findOne({ id: jwt_payload.id }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
it was the algorithms

```
const options = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: PUB_KEY,
  algorithms: ['RS256']
};
```

I removed "algorithms: ['RS256']" and it worked
(feeling a bit dum for solving that in 2 hours)